# Java 8: Converting Map<String, List<String>> to Map<String, String[]>

Tags: java, java-8, casting, hashmap, java-stream

```
Map<String, List<String>> parameters;

Map<String, String[]> collect = parameters.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry-> entry.getKey(),entry -> entry.getValue().toArray()));
```

I'm getting compiler error cannot resolve method 'getKey()'

Answer (score 3):

You should create an array of the correct type (i.e. a `String[]` and not an `Object[]`):

```
Map<String, String[]> collect = 
    parameters.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        entry -> entry.getValue().toArray(new String[0])));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use :

```
.toArray(String[]::new)
```

Instead of just :

```
.toArray()
```

because this one return `Object[]` not a `String[]`

As discussed in the comments my solution can be valid from [Java11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction))